# PHP PDO Update query not updating inside select query

Tags: php, database, pdo

So, i'm trying to make a script to collect YouTube channel data. I want to be able to update the data with a click of a button. Right now, it's not going through the users in my database and updating the information when the update query is in the while loop. When I make it so the bracket at the very end after the update query is right after the while loop, it'll update one record in the database. I need it to be able to loop through my database and update all users with the rank partner. Yes all the columns and everything are right because it does update it when not in the while loop, but just one user and not all.

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Rank = 'Partner'");
$query->execute();
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $channel = $row['Username'];



function findviews($channel) {

    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://socialblade.com/youtube/user/' . $channel);

    $gdatapage = curl_exec($ch);

    $gdatapage = strip_tags($gdatapage);
    $getviews = explode("Views for the Last 30 Days:",$gdatapage);
    $getviews = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$getviews[1]);
    $getviews = str_replace(",", "", trim($getviews));
    $getviews = explode(" S",$getviews);
    $getviews = str_replace(" ", "", trim($getviews[0]));

    curl_close($ch);

    return $getviews;

}

$views = findviews($channel);

  $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $channel);

$gdatapage = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match("/subscriberCount=\'([^\']*)\'/", $gdatapage, $subscribers);

curl_close($ch);
$subs = $subscribers[1];


$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE Users SET `Views` = :views, `Subs` = :subs WHERE `Username` = :channel");
$query->bindParam(':views', $views);
$query->bindParam(':subs', $subs);
$query->bindParam(':channel', $channel);
$query->execute();

}
```

Comment: Are the values you are binding all strings?

Comment: Defining a function inside a while?  Define that outside the loop, otherwise you are defining that function continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the `$query` which you are looping over when you write the first user:

```
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE Users SET `Views` = :views, `Subs` = :subs WHERE `Username` = :channel");
$query->bindParam(':views', $views);
$query->bindParam(':subs', $subs);
$query->bindParam(':channel', $channel);
$query->execute();
```

Change `$query` in this portion of the code to anything (`$q`?), and it will do what you need it to do for all the users

Comment: I think that might work, but now another problem came about. I got this `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare findviews() ` And thats this line `function findviews($channel) {`

Comment: Yes, take your `function findviews()` declaration outside of the loop. Otherwise you're trying to redefine it. Paste it at the top of your file (before your `while (...) {`) and you should be fine

Comment: Are you a wizard? Thank you so much, that worked completely and i've been trying to figure this out for about a week!

Comment: Are you still here? I have another problem with my login. I want to make it so both ranks can use the login, but it keeps blocking both of them, but if I only use one, it works fine. Heres my if statement  `if($rank != 'Admin' || $rank != 'Staff') {

    $message = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><div align='center'>You do not have permission to be viewing this page.</div></div>";

} else {` @charmeleon

Comment: OK, that's a logic issue. You want to change the condition in your `if` to `&&` instead of `||`. Think about why for a minute before you do so ;)

Comment: Hmm, but I don't need them to have both ranks... I need either or